# Can not run and build code which is on xCode4.2 with iPad with os 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios4

HI i am new in iPhone i have tried to build application on xcode4.2 and i have iPad with os 5.0 
but when i start application to run i got following message

**Xcode cannot run using the selected device.**

**No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.**

can anybody help me how to solve this problem i have tried so much but could not find any solution from googling also

Comment: When you select the project, can you make sure that the deployment target is 5.0. Because if the deployment target is 6.0, it is expecting a device with ios 6.0.

Comment: If you are new to iOS app development, why are you using such an old version of Xcode? The latest version (4.5.x) should be used so you can take advantage of features from iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

In your project's Build Settings, ensure that the deployment target is set to "iOS 5.0"

[image]